# Get HTML in the body after a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<body>
    <div id="someJunk">
        Content
    </div>
    <svg class=.....>
    <svg class=.....>
</body>
```

I need to get the svg's, either as a string or a list. How would I got about doing that?

Comment: To get the references: `$( '#someJunk' ).nextAll( 'svg' )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var svgs = [];

var start = document.getElementById("someJunk");
var svg;
do{
     svg = start.nextSibling;
    svgs.push(svg);
}
while(svg.tagName.toLowerCase()=="svg");
```

the svgs will be in the svgs array.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vanilla Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")
```

If you're using something like jQuery:

```
$("svg")
```

These will both get them as lists. You should be able to then get whatever information you need about them from that.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have other svg's up the page, but I specifically need the ones after the div.

Comment: I didn't realize you needed those particular svgs. I would probably give them some kind of identifying information and select on that, an id if possible. If you did that, you could simply use document.getElementById("yourId").

Answer (score 0):

You must check the nextElementSibling attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Put the svgs in their own div:

```
<div id="someJunk">
    Content
<div>
<div id="svgJunk">
  <svg class=.....>
  <svg class=.....>
<div>
```

Then access them by tag name and containing div:

```
var svgs = $("#svgJunk svg");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want all the elements **after** that element that match a certain criteria, use the jQuery `nextAll()` function:

```
$("#someJunk").nextAll("svg").fadeOut();
```

This example fades out all `svg` tags after that div.